# Sharing Programs in a Dropbox Folder

Tags: dropbox

I am currently storing config files in a dropbox folder (i.e., things like keyboard shortcuts).

The problem is that these keyboard shortcuts depend on certain programs to work (like xmodmap, xev, xcave, etc).

My idea is to put the compiled programs into a bin (inside dropbox) that all computers that have access to the Dropbox can access. **Is this possible?** Would it be better to store the binaries, or the file packages together so that they could be compiled for each particular computer locally?

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to include a setup script with the other resources, and the setup script would install the binaries using a reliable method. For example, if you know all your client systems are running rhel, you would just use something like "yum install xmodmap xev xcave". If running multiple distributions, you would need to add logic to handle that.

There are other ways to handle this situation that I would argue are "better", but also probably overengineered.